# Is it possible to access datastores from a Azure ML Service webservice?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

According to the Azure ML Service [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-access-data#access-datastores-during-training) it is possible to access datastores during training, but I couldn't find anything about using data from datastores inside the Webservice.

Even though is not necessary use external data to make an Webservice work, to use my model as I intend I need to use some datasets with features created based on historical data. For example: imagine that I'm trying to forecast if a client is going to pay a bill in the right date a good strategy is to create a feature based on previous payments of this same client.

The only external file that I could use in a Webservice is the 'model.pkl' which stores the ML model that I created previously.

How can I get an Azure ML webservice access a datastore?

Answer (score 1):

You can register multiple files as part of a "model" in the registry. You should include all pertinent files required for inference.

Keys are not provided to the inference service to access Azure ML datastores for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation page that you linked gives sample code to access files in a datastore. There are other samples in our [Notebook repo](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml) as well.

For example, you could look at this [specific example](https://aka.ms/pl-data-trans) that shows the datastore access clearly.

Code example:

```
# Blob store associated with your Azure ML workspace
blob_store = Datastore(ws, "workspaceblobstore")
# Upload a file to a container in the blob store
blob_store.upload_files(["./20news.pkl"], target_path="20newsgroups", overwrite=True)

# Access the previously uploaded file
blob_data = DataReference(
    datastore=blob_store,   
    data_reference_name="newsgroups_data",
    path_on_datastore="20newsgroups/20news.pkl")
```